# How can I check if a user have a quota on tablespace

Tags: oracle

My objective is to check users quotas on tablespace:

Unfortunately the table `dba_ts_quotas` gives the details of already used space on tablespaces.

I want to see all users who have quotas on tbs even they don't use any space on the tablespace.

is there solution to check if a user has quota on a tbs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DBA_TS_QUOTAS also contains information on the assigned quota, even if the user did not create any tables.

[From the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-484ABD92-CCEC-4550-9621-7B2BF301328C.htm#REFRN23294)

> `MAX_BYTES` - User's quota in bytes, or -1 if no limit

Example:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Tue Oct 18 10:35:29 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> select tablespace_name, username, bytes, max_bytes
  2  from dba_ts_quotas
  3  where tablespace_name = 'USERS'
  4    and username = 'FOOBAR';

no rows selected

SQL> create user foobar
  2    identified by welcome
  3    default tablespace users
  4    quota 10M on users;

User created.

SQL> select tablespace_name, username, bytes, max_bytes
  2  from dba_ts_quotas
  3  where tablespace_name = 'USERS'
  4    and username = 'FOOBAR';

TABLE USERNA      BYTES  MAX_BYTES
----- ------ ---------- ----------
USERS FOOBAR          0   10485760

1 row selected.

SQL>
```